# HTML table cell data expanding past div

Tags: html, css

The image basically shows what is happening. I have a wrapper of 1270px. Inside that wrapper (indicated by the vert line on the right) I have 4 divs and one table. The table contents is pushing past the page wrapper. THe page wrapper does not have a float as it is only to center the content on the page.

I have tried the following but nothing works:

```
border: none;
padding: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
overflow: hidden;
table-layout: fixed;
```

What is causing this? This is also allowing all the other content from the other 4 divs to push past the page wrapper as well.

[image]

EDIT:

```
<div id="wrap-page">
  <div id="wrap-content">
        <table id="content">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td id="featured">
                <h1>h1</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

                <h2>h2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
              </td>
              <td class="sidebar">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

html, body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:#ccc;
  font-size:100%;
  line-height:1;
  font-family:Arial;
}

#wrap-page{
  float:left;
  margin:auto;
  width:1270px;
}

#wrap-content{
  margin:0 5px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#content{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:1270px;
  margin:7px 0;
}

#featured{
  width:822px;
}

.sidebar{
  width:193px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Please, create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Can you post your code here for this?  Otherwise, people will just be guessing.

Comment: I suggest you to add some fiddle. Then your question will be more readable.

Comment: Posting the code on a fiddle is fine IF the code is posted here as well.  Links to external sites can change and/or go away making them irrelevant.

Comment: Add html + css code. Also, I am not exactly sure what tabular data I see above. You should reconsider your logical layout

Comment: Your inner table probably has a set width or you have an HTML error

Comment: Posted everything I've got. THanks for looking

Comment: this is not what tables are for

Comment: what browser is this in? Could be border box model

Comment: In FF, IE7 & 8 and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner divs widths and table is greater than your outer wrapper of 1270px.

Comment: I would agree with you but if I take the table all the way down to 500px, I still get a horz scrollbar. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Something is creating the scrollbar to appear. It may be your other inner divs. Post the code.

Comment: Kyle, without complicating this issue any more than it already is, suffice it to say that if you run exactly what I've posted, you should see the same exact thing I'm seeing. I narrowed the problem to this block of code.

Comment: Make the div to center the page smaller depending on your resolution. If you resolution is 1024 x 768 than anything over 1024 will have a scrollbar.

Comment: Kyle, I just came back to this and I noticed it too. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just trying to add a border to your text...

Please try this alternative (without tables):
http://jsfiddle.net/UXKTA/9/

```
.test
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
}​
```

Comment: Hmm... I've deleted the table totally and I still see the scrollbar. Your test is exactly 200px as it should be too.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, man. Can you edit my fiddle to replicate your issue, please?